# How to Optimize a Finite Element Model with Multiple Variables in Mathematica?

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization, finite-element-method, variable

Urgent Help, Please !!!

I am attaching my codes for a Finite Element Model which needs to be optimized and the **Objective Function ("of" in the code)** has been mentioned at the last line of the code. For optimizing the objective function, **all elements of Matrix "Va"** need to be changed continuously until the objective function's minimum/desired value is obtained. In the attached code, I have defined the matrix element as RandomChoice because I couldn't do anything to optimize these variables for the objective function.

I have used FindMinimum, NMinimize, etc., but neither worked at all. Somebody, please help me to optimize the attached finite element model.

**How can I optimize this Finite Element Model? Please help.**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
m = 2;    (*Linear Shape Function*)
(*All dimensions are in mm*)
b = 150;
ratio = 10;
a = b/ratio;
es = 5;                                                         \
(*Element size for FEA*)
noofnode = IntegerPart[((b - a)/es) + 1];
init = 0 &;
eb = 380;     (*MPa*)
ea = 71;       (*MPa*)
new = 0.3;                             (*Poisson's Ratio*)            \
      
gama = ea/(3*(1 - 2*new));  (*Bulk Modulus of A*)
miua = ea/(2*(1 + new));      (*Shear Modulus of A*)
gamb = eb/(3*(1 - 2*new));    (*Bulk Modulus of B*)
miub = eb/(2*(1 + new));         (*Shear Modulus of B*)
alphab = 8.0*10^(-6);
alphaa = 23.1*10^(-6);
rowb = 0.96;
rowa = 2.70;
Y = (miu*(9*gam + 8*miu))/(6*gam + 12*miu);
ta = 20;                      (*Degree C*)
tb = 150;  
xa = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];  
xad = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];  
f3[a5_] := (1*a5) + 0;
c = 0;
For[u1 = a, u1 < b + es, u1 += es,
  c = c + 1;
  c11 = (u1 - a)/(b - a);
  xa[[c]] = f3[c11];
  ];                  (*Degree C*)
c = 0;
For[u1 = a, u1 < b + es, u1 += es,
  c = c + 1;
  c11 = (b - u1)/(b - a);
  xad[[c]] = c11;
  ]; 
rpm = 150.0;
wom = (2.0*\[Pi]*rpm)/60;
kb = 35.0;
ka = 204.0;
lam = (1/(b - a))*
   Log[kb/ka];               (*Constant for Exponential Temp Profile*)


f[ri_] := ExpIntegralEi[-lam*ri];
c1 = (tb - ta)/(f[b] - f[a]);
c2 = ((ta*f[b]) - (tb*f[a]))/(f[b] - f[a]);
tf[rt_] := c2 + c1*ExpIntegralEi[-lam*rt];
drtf[rt_] = D[tf[rt], rt];
(*Shape Functions*)
phi1[rv_] := (5 - rv)/es;
phi2[rv_] := (rv/es);
phi[i_] := (2 - i)*phi1[rv] + (i - 1)*phi2[rv];
(*The derivatives of Shape Functions with respect to r*)
drphi1[rv_] := (-1/es);
drphi2[rv_] := (1/es);
drphi[i_] := (2 - i)*drphi1[rv] + (i - 1)*drphi2[rv];    
Va = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];      
Vaf = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];  
p = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];
c3 = 0;
f01[x3_] := (-0.0025*x3) + 0.0025;
For[u1 = a, u1 < b, u1 += es,
  c3 = c3 + 1;
  c4 = (u1 - a)/(b - a);
  p[[c3]] = f01[c4];
  ];      
ex = 0;
local = Array[
  init, {m, 
   m}];                                                 (*Matrix for \
Local Coordinate system*)
global = Array[
  init, {noofnode, 
   noofnode}];             (*Matrix for Global Coordinate system*)
(*LHS of GE*)
e = Array[
  init, {noofnode, 
   1}];                                    (*Modulus of Elasticity*)  \
                 
alpha = Array[
  init, {noofnode, 
   1}];                         (*Coefficient of Thermal Expansion*)
row = Array[
  init, {noofnode, 1}];                              (*Density*)
For[rb = a, rb < b, rb += es,
 ex = ex + 1;
 ex1 = ex + 1;
 Va = RandomChoice[Range[0, 1, 0.1], noofnode];
 Va[[1]] = 1;
 Va[[noofnode]] = 0;
 x = Values[
   NSolve[Va[[
         ex]]*((gama - gam)/(3*gama + 4*miu)) + (1 - 
          Va[[ex]])*((gamb - gam)/(3*gamb + 4*miu)) == 0 &&
     Va[[ex]]*((miua - miu)/(miua + Y)) + (1 - 
          Va[[ex]])*((miub - miu)/(miub + Y)) == 0, {gam, miu}, 
    Reals]];
 x2 = Dimensions[x];
 gam = x[[x2[[1]], 1]];
 miu = x[[x2[[1]], 2]];
 e[[ex]] = (9*gam*miu)/(3*gam + miu);
 alpha[[ex]] = 
  Va[[ex]]*alphaa*((gama*(3*gam + 4*miu))/(gam*(3*gama + 
          4*miu))) + (1 - Va[[ex]])*
    alphab*((gamb*(3*gam + 4*miu))/(gam*(3*gamb + 4*miu)));
 row[[ex]] = Va[[ex]]*rowa + (1 - Va[[ex]])*rowb;
 Clear[gam, miu];
 x = Values[
   NSolve[Va[[
         ex + 1]]*((gama - gam)/(3*gama + 4*miu)) + (1 - 
          Va[[ex + 1]])*((gamb - gam)/(3*gamb + 4*miu)) == 0 &&
     Va[[ex + 1]]*((miua - miu)/(miua + Y)) + (1 - 
          Va[[ex + 1]])*((miub - miu)/(miub + Y)) == 0, {gam, miu}, 
    Reals]];
 x1 = Dimensions[x];
 gam = x[[x1[[1]], 1]];
 miu = x[[x1[[1]], 2]];
 e[[ex + 1]] = (9*gam*miu)/(3*gam + miu);
 alpha[[ex + 1]] = 
  Va[[ex + 1]]*
    alphaa*((gama*(3*gam + 4*miu))/(gam*(3*gama + 4*miu))) + (1 - 
      Va[[ex + 1]])*
    alphab*((gamb*(3*gam + 4*miu))/(gam*(3*gamb + 4*miu)));
 row[[ex + 1]] = Va[[ex + 1]]*rowa + (1 - Va[[ex + 1]])*rowb;
 Clear[gam, miu];
 For[li = 1, li < m + 1, li++,
  For[lj = 1, lj < m + 1, lj++,
    ve = If[lj == 1, e[[ex]], e[[ex + 1]]];
    valpha = If[lj == 1, alpha[[ex]], alpha[[ex + 1]]];
    vrow = If[lj == 1, row[[ex]], row[[ex + 1]]];
    Cf1[ra_] := -((1/ra) - ((ve*drphi[lj])/
          e[[ex]]));                          (*Coefficient in the \
LHS of GE*)
    Cf2[ra_] := -((new*((ve*drphi[lj])/e[[ex]])) - (1/ra))/
      ra;                (*Coefficient in the LHS of GE*)
    ra = rb + r;
    rv = r;
    local[[li, lj]] = 
     NIntegrate[drphi[li]*drphi[lj], {r, 0, es}] + 
      NIntegrate[Cf1[ra]*(phi[li]*drphi[lj]), {r, 0, es}] + 
      NIntegrate[Cf2[ra]*(phi[li]*phi[lj]), {r, 0, es}];
    ];
  ];
 global[[ex, ex]] = global[[ex, ex]] + local[[1, 1]];
 global[[ex, ex + 1]] = local[[1, 2]];
 global[[ex + 1, ex]] = local[[2, 1]];
 global[[ex + 1, ex + 1]] = global[[ex + 1, ex + 1]] + local[[2, 2]];
 ];
globalf = 
  Take[global, {1, noofnode - 1}, {1, 
    noofnode - 1}];                                           
MatrixForm[globalf];                                         (*Final \
Global Matrix for LHS*)
ey = 0;
(*RHS of GE*)
(*Modulus of Elasticity, Coefficient of Thermal Expansion, and \
Density will change at each nodal point for generating the FGM*)
rhslocal = 
 Array[init, {m, 
   m}];                                       (*Matrix for Local \
Coordinate system*)
rhsglobal = 
 Array[init, {noofnode, 
   1}];                    (*Matrix for Global Coordinate system*)
For[rc = a, rc < b, rc += es,
 ey = ey + 1;
 For[ni = 1, ni < m + 1, ni++,
  For[nj = 1, nj < m + 1, nj++,
    ve = If[nj == 1, e[[ey]], e[[ey + 1]]];
    valpha = If[nj == 1, alpha[[ey]], alpha[[ey + 1]]];
    vrow = If[nj == 1, row[[ey]], row[[ey + 1]]];
    Cf0[rd_] := 
     e[[ey]]*alpha[[
        ey]]*((((valpha*drphi[nj])/alpha[[ey]])*tf[rd]) + drtf[rd]) - 
      row[[ey]]*wom^2*
       rd*((rd*((ve*drphi[nj])/e[[ey]])) - (rd*((vrow*drphi[nj])/
             row[[ey]])) - new - 3)*10^(-9);
    rd = rc + r1;
    rv = r1;
    rhslocal[[ni, nj]] = NIntegrate[Cf0[rd]*phi[ni], {r1, 0, es}];
    ];
  ];
 rhsglobal[[ey]] = 
  Re[rhsglobal[[ey]] + rhslocal[[1, 1]] + rhslocal[[1, 2]]];
 rhsglobal[[ey + 1]] = 
  Re[rhsglobal[[ey + 1]] + rhslocal[[2, 1]] + rhslocal[[2, 2]]];
 ];
MatrixForm[rhsglobal];
rhsglobalf = Take[rhsglobal, {1, noofnode - 1}];
MatrixForm[rhsglobalf];                                               \
                (*Final Global Matrix for RHS*)
sol = LinearSolve[globalf, 
  rhsglobalf];                              (*Determining the values \
of F*)
solf = Insert[sol, 
  0, {-1}];                                                       \
(*Implementing BC*)
stress = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];
cstress = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];                    
ez = 0;
For[re = a, re < b, re += es,
  ez = ez + 1;
  rf = re + rg;
  fv[rg_] := (solf[[ez]]*phi1[rg]) + (solf[[ez + 1]]*phi2[rg]);
  sr[rg_] = fv[rg]/rf;
  stress[[ez]] = sr[0];
  stress[[ez + 1]] = sr[es];
  cstress[[ez]] = 
   solf[[ez]]*drphi1[0] + solf[[ez + 1]]*drphi2[0] + 
    10^(-9)*row[[ez]]*wom^2*(re)^2;
  cstress[[ez + 1]] = 
   solf[[ez]]*drphi1[es] + solf[[ez + 1]]*drphi2[es] + 
    10^(-9)*row[[ez + 1]]*wom^2*(re + es)^2;
  ];     
str = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];      
cstr = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];      
For[i = 1, i < noofnode + 1, i++,
  str[[i]] = stress[[i, 1]];
  cstr[[i]] = cstress[[i, 1]];
  ];
of = Sqrt[
   Sum[((str[[j]] - p[[j]])^2), {j, 1, noofnode}]/
    Sum[((str[[j]])^2), {j, 1, noofnode}]];
```

Comment: You have much better chances to get a good answer by providing a minimal example, not the full code.

Comment: What do you try to solve?

Comment: I am trying to determine stresses (str) along the radial distance of an FGM disk to compare the results with a prescribed stress profile. In addition, for determining the stresses which agree with the prescribed profile, the Volume Fractions (Va) need to be predicted. Therefore, my main objective is to predict the volume fractions to determine the prescribed stresses, which means it is an inverse problem.

Comment: In what sense did `FindMinimum, NMinimize, etc., not worked at all.  Show the code you used and describe the problems you encountered.

Comment: I tried to optimize the objective function "of" mentioned in the last line of the code, where all the "Va" Matrix elements are the variables. Then I have got continuous error messages instead of getting the solution. The messages are "NSolve::ratnz: NSolve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.", "The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries", etc.

Comment: @SazedurRahman Do you try to optimize `of` with variable `Va`? What about boundary elements: should we hold ` Va[[1]] = 1; Va[[noofnode]] = 0;` in optimization as well? Also, can you show part of code with initial data that not involved in optimization?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes, I want to optimize `of` with variable `Va` . That means all elements of the `Va ` matrix will be variable to optimize where `Va[[1]] = 1` and `Va[[noofnode]] = 0`. Most important thing is that `Va` matrix must be initiated at the starting and without the values of ` Va ` other code cannot be executed. Without numerical values of `Va` matrix **NSolve::ratnz: NSolve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients, The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries, etc.** errors appear continuously