# Optimization with NDSolve

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Multiple variables involved in NDSolve need to be optimized. Previously, I shared my codes but didn’t get any helpful response. Please tell me how can I optimize multiple variables (say 30 or 40) involved in NDSolve?

Comment: Can you make a MWE? as far as I know `NDSolve` is used to solve differential equations. I did not know it can also be used for optimization. So an small example with what you tried will help

Comment: Related?: [(262504)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262504), [(262662)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262662)

Comment: @Nasser Please go through https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263113/findminimum-running-forever?noredirect=1#comment655382_263113 This is my post

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes those were my post but I didn't get any solution from anybody. Therefore I updated my codes for optimization by myself. The problem is the code keeps running without giving any output. Here is the code, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263113/findminimum-running-forever?noredirect=1#comment655382_263113 This is my post

Comment: You did not get any response because it is a complicated problem. You want to optimize 30-40 parameters on top of NDSolve? Even to optimize much simpler function that does not involve NDSolve is not easy. You need to start with something simple that is working. For instance try fixing all but one parameters.

Comment: @SazedurRahman To solve your problem  about FGM disk stress it could be better to formulate problem as it is in mathematical notation and then show your attempt. May be we don't need to solve optimization problem.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Here is my attempt https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263113/findminimum-running-forever?noredirect=1#comment655382_263113

Comment: @SazedurRahman It could be better to explain your problem in mathematical symbols as well, since I don't understand what do you try to solve with your code on  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263113/findminimum-running-forever?noredirect=1#comment655382_263113

Comment: @SazedurRahman Please, see my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263113/findminimum-running-forever?noredirect=1#comment655382_263113